# MySQL - Exclude in group_concat using regex

Tags: mysql

I am running a query that returns an array of categories and subcategories which are indicated by either an i,[digit] or a c,[digit].

I have managed to get the concatenation working a replacement for the i so I can then run a query in PHP against a different table where i is represented as a simple id.

NOW, I want to EXCLUDE anything with c,[x number of digits] in the results.

I've managed to get the regex working via regexPal (great tool!), but can't seem to get it working in MySQL.

Original Query

```
 select id, name, (Group_concat(replace(replace(arrange, 'i,', ''), '|', ','))) As  
 Products from cats
 where id = '19'
```

The output of this is:

```
 c,4331,c,290,c,292,c,282,c,284,c,285,c,4230,c,4228,c,4229,c,298,c,299,c,395,c,396,c,393,c,288,78,81
```

Now, I added this line to the query:

```
 and arrange not regexp "c,[0-9]{1,10},"
```

The expected output is 78, 81. But I am still getting the full output as above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How about `HAVING products NOT REGEXP "c,[0-9]{1,10},"`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think it has to be something to do with the format of the RegEx and MySQL - because it's either returning 0 or All results.

Comment: A(n) sqlfiddle and/or proper DDLs might be useful.

Comment: Well that's a new tool to me! Brilliant - does this help? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25377/1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this via the PHP function of preg_replace instead using this excellent tool at http://www.phpliveregex.com/

I passed the query results into the preg_replace, it then performed the correct regex lookup to exclude the matching elements of the string.

$prodsarray2 = preg_replace("/c,[0-9]{0,10},/", "", $prodsarray);

So it goes:

NEW STRING = preg_replace(REGULAR EXPRESSION, REPLACEMENT TEXT, LOOKUP STRING)